# liferay unasign user to delete organizations

Tags: liferay-6

I'm new to Liferay and work on a site done with Liferay 6.1.1.

I have a question about deleting organization. When I try to delete an organization, I have an error message

> You cannot delete organizations that have suborganizations or users.

I found that before deleting the organization, I had to delete this organization's site and unasign all user manually, then the organization can be delete without error.

Does anybody know if it is possible to add a property or edit the delete function so when you try to delete an organization it'll do the previous task automatically ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not possible to achieve/fulfill your requirement just by setting property. However, you can achieve this by creating `Hook` in liferay. Inside hook you can use below Liferay's api :

- For deleting sub organization you can use `OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getSuborganizations(long companyId, long organizationId)` which will return list of sub organization. You can iterate this list and call `OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.deleteOrganization(long organizationId)` which will delete sub organization.
- To Unassigned users from org,
  use `UserLocalServiceUtil.clearOrganizationUsers(long organizationId)`

HTH